# GOLANG + MONGODB: Get count of all comments in a post

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation

Im currently using aggregation to get the user who created a post and populate the user field in the post struct. I would like to find all comments where `post_id`: `_id` _id being the _id of the post.

This is my current code which currently returns the post with the user.

```
func GetPostFeed() ([]models.PostResponse, error) {
    postCollection := DB.Database("wecrypto").Collection("posts")
    var postFeed []models.PostResponse
    lookupStage := bson.D{
        bson.E{
            Key: "$lookup",
            Value: bson.M{
                "from":         "users",
                "localField":   "user_id",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as":           "user",
            },
        },
    }

    //groupStage := bson.D{
    //    bson.E{
    //        Key: "$group",
    //        Value: bson.M{
    //            "_id": "$post_id",
    //            "$commentCount": bson.E{
    //                Key:   "$sum",
    //                Value: 1,
    //            },
    //        },
    //    },
    //}
    unwindStage := bson.D{
        bson.E{
            Key: "$unwind",
            Value: bson.M{
                "path": "$user",
            },
        },
    }
    filterCursor, err := postCollection.Aggregate(context.Background(), mongo.Pipeline{lookupStage, groupStage, unwindStage})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err = filterCursor.All(context.Background(), &postFeed)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return postFeed, nil
}
```

expected result:

```
{
   "id": "61ef6586a629895408c149b8",
   "body": "This is the body of the test posts",
   "isTrending": false,
   "tags": [],
   "user": {
      "id": "61eb91801579dd486ba0099e",
      "username": "bob",
      "avatarURL": "string.url"
   },
   "mentions": [],
   "commentCount": 4    <----- this is what I want. 
}
```

Comment: does `GetPostFeed()` function return a value or an error?

Comment: @hisam It returns either an error or an array.

Answer (score 1):

If your posts and comments are in different scema and are linked by a "foreign key" or id, i.e something like so...

```
// Posts
[
{
    _id: 1
    content: 'Post 1'
},
{
    _id: 2
    content: 'Post 2'
}
]

// Comments
[
{
    _id: 1,
    post: 1,
    content: 'Content 1'
},
{
    _id: 2,
    post: 1,
    content: 'Content 1'
}
]
```

Then you can count the number of comments for each post in a pipeline like so

```
[
  ...
{
          $lookup: {
            from: 'comments',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'post',
            as: 'postComments'
          }
        },
         {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            content: 1,
              commentCount: {
                $size: '$postComments'
              }
          }
        }
]
```